# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to insert a value into an array but when i try to insert the value it gives me the Connot set Property '0' of undefined. But clearly i defined the array already.

Error Line:

```
this.enemyMinions[i] = new EnemyCombatMinion(new Minion(enemyMinionInfo[0], 0, enemyMinionInfo[1], enemyMinionInfo[2], enemyMinionInfo[3], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
```

And this is the entire code:

```
function Combat() {
  this.enemyMinions = [];
  this.playerMinions = [];
  this.currentEnemyMinion = null;
  this.currentPlayerMinion = null;
}

Combat.prototype.initialize = function() {
  var o = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < partySlots.length; i++) {
    if(partySlots[i]) {
      this.playerMinions[o] = PlayerCombatMinion(partySlots[i]);
      o++;
    }
  }
  this.currentPlayerMinion = this.playerMinions[0];

   $.ajax({
      url: "./api/generateEnemyCombatMinions.php",
      cache: false
    })
    .done(function( html ) {          
      var response = html.split(":::");
      for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        var enemyMinionInfo = response[i].split("::");
        this.enemyMinions[i] = new EnemyCombatMinion(new Minion(enemyMinionInfo[0], 0, enemyMinionInfo[1], enemyMinionInfo[2], enemyMinionInfo[3], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
      }
      alert(this.enemyMinions.length);
    });   

}
```

As you see, i declared this.enemyMinons as a literal in the class constructor, and try to define a value to it in the initialize method.

Comment: is `var enemyMinionInfo = response[i].split("::");` returning an array?

Comment: Your problem is that `this` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: check "this" out, it may not be what you think

Answer (score 5):

The `done()` callback does not use your `Combat` object as `this`. Save a pointer to the object in the `initialize()` function, so that you can access the object later on.

```
Combat.prototype.initialize = function() {
  var o = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < partySlots.length; i++) {
    if(partySlots[i]) {
      this.playerMinions[o] = PlayerCombatMinion(partySlots[i]);
      o++;
    }
  }
  this.currentPlayerMinion = this.playerMinions[0];

  // this is new
  var that= this;

   $.ajax({
      url: "./api/generateEnemyCombatMinions.php",
      cache: false
    })
    .done(function( html ) {          
      var response = html.split(":::");
      for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        var enemyMinionInfo = response[i].split("::");
        // use "that" here instead of "this"
        that.enemyMinions[i] = new EnemyCombatMinion(new Minion(enemyMinionInfo[0], 0, enemyMinionInfo[1], enemyMinionInfo[2], enemyMinionInfo[3], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
      }
      alert(that.enemyMinions.length);
    });   

}
```

Comment: adding to this: "this" is not the java this, meaning it does not refer to caller but to "scope". read up on scope, it's one of the most important aspects of understanding js. short, in JS functions create scope, so inside your done-callback, this is the scope of the callback.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sirko and DatProgram.. I am pretty new to JS, well, iv used to for some time now but for very small things. Im creating a project which is mainly javascript based (except for some MySQL things which i use ajax for) in order to understand javascript more. I will definitely look up more about these scope's in javascript..